# Hibernate joining two tables

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Spring and Hibernate . I have the following form

[image]

After inserting the form values in my database tables, I want them to look like following:

**Table Name : student**

```
student_id    studentName
  1.           Jason Stathum
```

**Table Name : studentdetails**

```
studentDetailsid   FatherName   MotherName    student_id
   1                 Mr.X          Mrs. Y        1
```

But when I actually insert values in my database, the `studentdetails` table looks like following

**Table Name : studentdetails**

```
studentDetailsid   FatherName   MotherName    student_id
   1                 Mr.X          Mrs. Y        NULL
```

As you can see everything works perfectly but only the `student_id` column doesn't get filled up. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here's are my codes:

**Model Class : Student**

```
package com.spring.org.model

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="student_id", nullable= false)
private Integer studentId;
private String studentName;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student")
private List<StudentDetails> studentDetails = new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();

// Getters and Setters
```

**Model Class : StudentDetails**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "studentDetails")
public class StudentDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer studentDetailsId;
private String FatherName;
private String MotherName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="student_id")
private Student student;

// Getters and Setters
```

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="addstudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("secret") Student student, BindingResult result, Model map)
{
    map.addAttribute("student", new Student());     
    return "addStudent";
}

@RequestMapping(value="addstudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("secret") Student student, BindingResult result, Model map)
{
    studentService.addStudent(student);
    map.addAttribute("success", "Submitted");
    return "msg";

}
```

**JSP Page : Form**

```
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/addstudent" />
 <form:form modelAttribute="secret" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">
  <table>
  <tr>
     <td><form:label path="studentName">Student Name:</form:label></td>
     <td><form:input path="studentName"/></td>
 </tr> 

 <tr>
    <td><form:label path="studentDetails[0].FatherName">Father Name:</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="studentDetails[0].FatherName"/></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td><form:label path="studentDetails[0].MotherName">Mother Name:</form:label></td>
   <td><form:input path="studentDetails[0].MotherName"/></td>
 </tr>
</table>

 <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form:form>
```

**StudentDaoImpl**

```
@Override
public void addStudent(Student student) {

    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx;
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(student);  

    tx.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `@JoinColumn` annotation from the `student` attribute in `StudentDetails` should fix the issue:

```
@ManyToOne
//@JoinColumn(name="student_id")
private Student student;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just removed `@JoinColumn(name="student_id")` and ran my application but still its not working. It changed my column name to `student_student_id` from `student_id`. Thanks

Comment: this is strange, `student_id` should be the default column name. Using JoinColumn here is not wrong, it should be redundant. As the StudentDetails do get stored, the cascade seems to be working - even stranger.

Comment: Is the foreign key properly stored if you (supposedly redundantly) save or merge the StudentDetails after saving the Student?

Answer (score 0):

Change this fragment:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="student_id")
private Student student;
```

to:

```
@ManyToOne
private Student student;
```

and this should work.

Comment: what is the difference to my (earlier) answer?

Comment: I am still getting NULL

Comment: @kostja simply race condition while editing answer. It doesn't seem to work anyway.

Comment: two wrongs does not make a right so it seems :), no problem

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem, I hope this will help others someday. 
I made some changes in my

**Model Class: Student**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="student_id", nullable= false)
private Integer studentId;
private String studentName;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName="student_id")
private List<StudentDetails> studentDetails = new ArrayList<StudentDetails>();

// Getters and Setters
```

And then removed the `private Student student;` property from Model Class: StudentDetails. So now it looks like this:

Model Class : StudentDetails

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "studentDetails")
public class StudentDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer studentDetailsId;
private String FatherName;
private String MotherName;

// Getters and Setters
```